# JavaScript: Set Variable

Tags: javascript

I'm using http://fakeapp.com to run some browser automation tasks and am running into a bit of a roadblock with parsing in a variable to the URL string. This question is more about JavaScript loops than FakeApp (but just so question has some context). Here's what I have so far:

```
var idx = fake.loop.index;
fake.set('idx', idx);
console.log('idx: ' + idx)
```

What I need to do is just set the starting variable at let's say `500`. Right now the repeatable action (this part is done in FakeApp) starts at 0 -- I need to start the index at a specific number and increment by one. Thanks!

Comment: There's no "loop" in the code you posted.

Comment: I think you need to provide more code, it's very hard to help you with what you've posted now!

Comment: Can you try **fake.loop.index = 500;**

Comment: I guess that shows how far along I am with this :) Possibly the wrong title for the question then (I'll update) but it's more about setting `idx` to equal (or start) with `500`. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisGessler No dice on that - thank you though - I know this isn't as complete of a question as it could be, but I am willing to try and give any other info needed. Thanks.